# Escape string for javascript: hex in json

Tags: javascript, json, hex

This string

> {\x22Address\x22:\x22some address with quotes \x22}

is parsed by JSON.parse correctly in browser. Why? What do hex numbers mean in json string? I can't find explanation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Javascript a backslash is an escape character. There are several escape sequences, you can [find a list here](http://www.javascriptkit.com/jsref/escapesequence.shtml).

The most important:

- `\x` followed by two hexadecimal characters represent a character by it's ascii code
- `\u` followed by four hexadecimal characters represent a character by it's unicode number
- `\t`, `\r`, `\n` you certainly know already. They are tab, carriage return and new line respectively.

Comment: Important note! This is a property of JavaScript strings, *not JSON strings*.
Ref [json.org](https://www.json.org/) and section 9 of the [ECMA standard](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-404.pdf).

Answer (score 2):

If you look up the hex value 22 in a ascii table, you can see that its the quote sign ( " ). Thats why its parsed correctly. http://www.asciitable.com/

```
var str= "{\x22test\x22: \x22hello\x22}";
var test = JSON.parse(str);
console.dir(test);
```

{ test: 'hello' }

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
console.log(decodeURIComponent("\x22")); // `"`
```

See [ascii Chart](http://defindit.com/ascii.html)